# Select years from datetime column returning new list with distinct years Linq To SQL vb.net

Tags: linq-to-sql, datetime

I have a column with datetime and want to get the destinct years in a new list.

The goal is to populate a DropDownList with the distinct years only (YYYY, not YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) extracted from the Games.Date column.

Objects I have:

```
LDSYears (LinqDataSource)
LDSUserResults (LinqDataSource)
DropDownList1
LDSYears_Selecting (LinqDataSourceSelectEvent)
GridView1
```

I was thinking that I would use the LDSYears to populate the DropDownList1, then use the DropDownList1 as a Where statement in the LDSUserResults to filter only user results from the year that was selected in the DropDownList1.

The LinqDataSourceSelectEvent is where the codes is located. The reason I have this code in the Event is that, what I have read it's not possible to use destinct in a LinqDataSource, and I also want to trim the output to year-only, not the datetime.

```
Protected Sub LDSYears_Selecting(sender As Object, _
        e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs) _
    Handles LDSYears.Selecting

    Dim years = From dy In (From ys In db.Games _
                            Where ys.Date.Year.ToString <> "" Distinct _
                            Select ys.ID, ys.Date Distinct) _
                        Select dy _
                        Order By dy.Date Descending
    e.Result = years
End Sub
```

Games.Date column:

```
2009-01-10 09:00:00
2009-03-10 09:00:00
2010-02-10 09:00:00
2010-03-10 09:00:00
2011-01-10 09:00:00
2011-03-10 09:00:00
```

And I want a new list like this to be populated to my DropDownList, ID for index, and Years for Value:

```
ID Years
1  2011
2  2010
3  2009
```

Maybe I'm looking at this at the wrong angle, It'should be possible?

I can do this by code, but I thought it was a better way to use the DropDownList as a filter to LDSUserResults.

Comment: What does the ID property correspond to...a Game?

Comment: If the ID property is a unique Game ID then this probably wont work because you don't know which game ID to return with which Year. Anyhow, if there are not too many results you can get the distinct years by (From ys In db.Games Select ys.Date.Year).Distinct...in linq to objects anyways. Just keep in mind that this will likely return all results first then do a distinct. Hope that helps.

Comment: I basicly want to populate the years only to a DropDownList thats why I need a ID for the index and the Years for the value, so I wont be using them to access the database directly, the ID's could be someting complety diffrent then from the original db ID. I will then use the control (DropDownList with the years) in a LinqDataSource to filer the years of the games (dates) and display only the games from the selected year.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like all you really need to do is select the distinct years and you do not need the ID. Why not just use the year instead of the ID for both, would that work? If so, it would be `(From ys In db.Games Select ys.Date.Year).Distinct`

The problem with the ID is that if two games have the same year then which ID do you return?

Comment: That would return all the games because all dates are unique as you can se from the 'Column "Date"'. As stated in my comment to Craig's question I will not use the result to access the database directly, just to populate the years to a DropDownList containing, in this example, 2011, 2010 and 2009.

Comment: Sorry bare with me I am still a little confused. Does ys.Date not have a Year property? Do you want the unique year from db.Games?

Comment: I have this code (part of it) in a LinqDataSourceSelectEvent that is used by a DropDownList, maybe I'm not thinking straigt. I will explain more in detail, will edit my Question, sorry for the lack of detail, but tried to be sparse.

Comment: No worries, the guys in my fantasy hockey draft are bombing tonight anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're OK with a list of `Integer` along with the index, you can simply do:

```
Dim years = (From dy In dc.Dates 
                Select dy.Date1.Year).Distinct().OrderByDescending(Function(year) year).AsEnumerable().Select(Function(year, index) New With {index, year})

Response.Write(String.Join(", ", years))
```

As Craig pointed out, if all you're doing is binding to a DDL, you don't need the ID. Each list item of your DDL inherently has an index you can use.

Comment: That's pretty good, is it possible to get just the date as a string or is it more complex? have removed the index and doing it the old uggly way to populate the DDL with the result